# How to Inherit from two or more classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

So I have a classes

```
function Node()
{
Node.prototype.setName=function(_n){this.Name=_n;};
}
function TextableNode()
{
TextableNode.prototype.setText=function(_t) {this.text=_t;};
}
function AttributionalNode()
{
AttributionalNode.prototype.setAttribute=function(_a) {this.att=_a;};
}
```

All of these inherited from Node(); but how to implement new class such as UniversalNode(); that will have all this methods?

Comment: A better question would be why on earth would you want to. Multiple inheritance is often more trouble than it's worth and should make you pause and rethink how you are organizing things.

Comment: You don't have classes. Javascript doesn't have classes (although ECMA 6 introduces syntactic sugar for them). Start here for a better understanding of inheritance in JS: [**You Don't Know JS: *this* & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md).